# copy datatable rows from one table to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

`queryDataTable` has the data within it and if the check is true that the row contrains that word it add that whole row to the `extractedData`.. but at the moment there is only two rows to be added to the `extractedData` datatable but when I inspect the data there is 22 row added to it is there any reason for this the code is below

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

for (int k = 0; k < queryDataTable.Rows.Count; k++)
{

    string row = "";
    string test = queryDataTable.Rows[k][0].ToString();
    bool check = queryDataTable.Rows[k][0].ToString().StartsWith(queryString);
    if (check)
    {
        int errorcheck = k;
        extractedData.ImportRow(queryDataTable.Rows[errorcheck]);

    }
}
```

how would i only add a row at a certain index in the first datatable

Comment: Check your data. I guess there might be ` ` at the beginning of some rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the entire row this code can't work, with this instruction:

```
queryDataTable.Rows[k][0].ToString().StartsWith(queryString);
```

you check only the first column of the k-row.
First, you can use this more compact code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
   if(r[0].startsWith(queryString))
   {
      extractedData.ImportRow(r);
   }
}
```

The if statament checks only the column 0 of each rows. If you specify to me the check that you want to do i can try to modify this code or create a linq query.

Comment: the word row give a miss referance do u know y

Comment: I'm sorry i write Row instead of DataRow

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this. (StartsWith checks if a string startswith a substring).

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

// Here we add five DataRows.
table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

var rows = table.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => dr.ItemArray.Contains("David"));

DataTable copyTable = new DataTable();
copyTable.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
copyTable.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
copyTable.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
copyTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    copyTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
}
```

Sample data taken from https://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable